# nomad: Pull docker image from ECR with AWS Access and Secret keys

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-ecr, nomad

## My problem

I have successfully deployed a nomad job with a few dozen Redis Docker containers on AWS, using the default Redis image from Dockerhub.

I've slightly altered the default config file created by `nomad init` to change the number of running containers, and everything works as expected

The problem is that the actual image I would like to run is in [ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/ecr/), which requires AWS permissions (access and secret key), and I don't know how to send these.

## Code

```
job "example" {
  datacenters = ["dc1"]
  type = "service"
  update {
    max_parallel = 1
    min_healthy_time = "10s"
    healthy_deadline = "3m"
    auto_revert = false    
    canary = 0
  }    
  group "cache" {
    count = 30    
    restart {
      attempts = 10
      interval = "5m"    
      delay = "25s"    
      mode = "delay"
    }    
    ephemeral_disk {    
      size = 300
    }    
    task "redis" {
      driver = "docker"    
      config {

    # My problem here

    image = "https://-whatever-.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/-whatever-"
        port_map {
          db = 6379
        }
      }
      resources {
        network {
          mbits = 10
          port "db" {}
        }
      }
      service {
        name = "global-redis-check"
        tags = ["global", "cache"]
        port = "db"
        check {
          name     = "alive"
          type     = "tcp"
          interval = "10s"
          timeout  = "2s"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## What have I tried

- Extensive Google Search
- Reading [the manual](https://www.nomadproject.io/docs/drivers/docker.html#auth_file)
- Placing the `aws` credentials in the machine which runs the nomad file (using `aws configure`)

## My question

How can nomad be configured to pull Docker containers from AWS ECR using the AWS credentials?

Comment: Interesting that this stays unanswered and google search shows this question in first 5 results. Also your reputation assumes you know to read the documentation so the question is not without prior research. People are still looking for this.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty late for you, but aws ecr does not handle authentication in the way that docker expects. There you need to run `sudo $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ${your region})` Running the returned command actually authenticates in a docker compliant way

Note that region is optional if aws cli is configured. Personally, I allocate an IAM role the box (allowing ecr pull/list/etc), so that I don't have to manually deal with credentials.

Answer (score -1):

I don't use ECR, but if it acts like a normal docker registry, this is what I do for my registry, and it works. Assuming the previous sentence, it should work fine for you as well:

```
config {
                image = "registry.service.consul:5000/MYDOCKERIMAGENAME:latest"
                auth {
                    username = "MYMAGICUSER"
                    password = "MYMAGICPASSWORD"
                }
            }
```